# File-based, not Folder-based, Projects in Atom?

Tags: ide, atom-editor, bbedit

I'm trying to switch to Atom as my programming editor so that I can gain handy features like linting for Perl, JavaScript, etc. However, over the last two decades, I've used a string of editors (UltraEdit, jEdit, BBEdit) that allowed me to add individual files from different folders into projects. My main coding project actually spans several remote SFTP servers and the "folders" in my BBEdit project do not necessarily correspond to any file structure on disk.

I cannot seem to figure out how to set up a project in this manner in Atom (or similar editors such as Brackets). Is there a way to configure Atom and its extensions to produce a result similar to an UltraEdit/jEdit/BBEdit/Komodo project? I thought about creating a new project directory and symlinking to the real files, but that seems like a hack at best.

Answer (score 0):

I belive its `File > Open Project` or something like that. I personally like Sublime Text 3 but Atom and Sublime are the same.

Comment: Thanks @Ahmed. As far as I can tell, Atom doesn't allow adding individual files to its standard projects. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I have found so far would be to install [`opened-files`](https://atom.io/packages/opened-files) package. By default it persists all files you have opened (even after you close them) until you close atom editor. I don't think it would work well for bigger projects as it lists all the files under one tab in tree view.

If you want to persist open files you might want to use [`project-manager`](https://atom.io/packages/project-manager) package. To keep files listed under 'Opened files' tab after you close them (and atom), you need to press bookmark icon next to tab name. Once you add the project it auto-saves file structure when you close atom. To add project to project-manager write `project-manager save` in command palette. To list all projects from project manager press `shift-alt-P`.